# Transform a given date into a desired dateformat using js Date Object - performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

today i wrote a universal datetransformer for js - date.

Now before i add this methode to in my own lib to the date object i hope to get some tips to make this methode so performant as possible.

Description:
parameter 'initVal' is the given valid date
parameter 'format' is the desired dateformat as String eg 'd.m.Y'

For the 'format' i'm using the date parameters from php http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

There are several Questions in which i'm not sure eg.:

is switch'n'case the most suitability choice?
would it be better to avoid using jquery-routines for the each-iteration?
and else ? are there any nogos?

**thx a lot** for your suggestions!

```
var getWellDate = function(initVal, format){
    var dateObj = new Date(initVal);
    var strArr = format.split('');
    var returnVal = '';
    var tempVal = '';

    $.each(strArr, function (index, value) {
        switch (value){
            case 'd' : // day with leading zero
            case 'j' :
                tempVal = dateObj.getDate();
                returnVal += tempVal < 10 && value == 'd' ? '0' + tempVal : tempVal;
                break;
            case 'm' : // month with leading zero
            case 'n' :
                var tempVal = dateObj.getMonth() + 1;
                returnVal += tempVal < 10 && value == 'm' ? '0' + tempVal : tempVal;
                break;
            case 'Y' : // year 4 digits
            case 'y' : // year 2 digits
                tempVal = dateObj.getFullYear();
                returnVal += value == 'Y' ? tempVal : tempVal.match(/\d{2}$/);
                break;
            default :
                returnVal += value;
        }
    });

    return returnVal;
}
```

Maybe the function is also for others useful. ive stored in in bitbucked - just asc for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely check out how well-known date handler libs do date formatting. Examples:

- [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)
- [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: jesus christ -> what im doing?? 
its just a line per moment.js
var returnVal = moment(initVal*1000).format("DD.MM.YYYY");
ths plugin is just minified 6,x k 
thx!